# Scrolling file list with selectable files in Android

Tags: android, user-interface

I am a beginner in Android development and starting my second Android project - a network based file sharing application. I want to show a list of files, that I'll fetch from a network resource, on the screen in which the user can scroll through the files and select multiple files. Each file information will have the *filename* in larger point size followed by *filesize* and *source info* in the next line in small point size. I want the list exactly like the list which appears when you press *Options > Multi-select* in *Root Explorer* android application. Any inputs, how may I go about laying out the user interface, will be highly appreciated.
A bit of search revealed that it is a frequently used pattern 
http://www.androidpatterns.com/uap_pattern/slide-to-scroll

but being a beginner in Android Development(UI development broadly) I am unable to lay out my UI. I tried ScrollView as a parent of vertically oriented LinearLayout with several TextViews inside but that doesn't seem to be what I need.

Update:And yeah, I also want to place some buttons like Download, View information in the bottom just like they are placed in Root Explorer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `ListView` with a custom adapter.

This example that you can find on the Internet provides an *exact* behavior of what you want to achieve as in Root Explorer.

The difference is that where that example `extends ArrayAdapter`, you would need to set the `TextView` text size to something smaller or bigger, depending on what you need.

I can clarify if you need. But I don't think you'll need more than that if you follow the link I gave to you.

Start experimenting and you'll see that it's quite easy once you get the feeling.

*edit: oops, I forgot the link. [Here it is](http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/).

Comment: ps.: don't worry, UI design is a bit complicated at first. I don't like it much also, and I generally stick with the best practices that the Google people make available to us in code samples and examples.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that out and get back. But you probably forgot to post the example link.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot. But I quickly added it (while and) before you even commented. ;-) Besides, if you want other examples, always search for "listview custom adapter". That is the pattern/keywords you want to follow!